# Language without explicit memory alloc/dealloc AND without garbage collection

Tags: pointers, memory, garbage-collection

I was wondering if it is possible to create a programming language without explicit memory allocation/deallocation (like C, C++ ...) AND without garbage collection (like Java, C#...) by doing a full analysis at the end of each scope?

The obvious problem is that this would take some time at the end of each scope, but I was wondering if it has become feasible with all the processing power and multiple cores in current CPU's. Do such languages exist already?

I also was wondering if a variant of C++ where smart pointers are the only pointers that can be used, would be exactly such a language (or am I missing some problems with that?).

Edit:
Well after some more research apparently it's this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting
I was wondering why this isn't more popular. The disadvantages listed there don't seem quite serious, the overhead should be that large according to me. A (non-interpreted, properly written from the ground up) language with C family syntax with reference counting seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: The problem with reference counting is cyclic references: if a parent has a list of children and every child knows his parent, the whole tree will never be deallocated.

Comment: Reference counting is a method for implementing a garbage collection system. Are you asking for a system that doesn't allow any dynamic allocation, or you asking about a system that has dynamic allocation that is different from a mark and sweep algorithm?

Comment: Also, enforcing a memory management strategy is best left to policy decisions. Languages like C and C++ can support reference counting or other dynamic memory management schemes quite nicely, and they don't get in the way when you want to do thing your way. If you used a language that enforced these policies, you're sooner or later going to need to step around them for some project. Then your language doesn't meet your needs. See my post below if you're looking for enforce these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem with reference counting is that it is not a complete solution and is not capable of collecting a cyclic structure. The overhead is incurred every time you *set* a reference; for many kinds of problems this adds up quickly and can be worse than just waiting for a GC later. (Modern GC is quite advanced and awesome - don't count it down like that!!!)

Comment: There are a few ways to detect cycles in reference count based GC. Non of them is cheap though.

Comment: You would basicaly be doing a mark-sweep colletcion by the time you try to detect those cycles like that.

Comment: That would be the trivial way of dealing with that problem, but there are [other solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Dealing_with_reference_cycles).

Comment: weak references is cheating :P

Comment: Modern garbage collection is good for **most** problems. If you have a server with 50GB of tiny objects (like in a cache), not so much. It can take 30 seconds or more to scan the heap, and I haven't seen a system yet where the oldest heap doesn't lock down the entire process. If you tried to implement a caching server with a GC language, the latency during GC would make it completely unusable.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is nothing special, and it shows up all the time. The C or C++ variant you are looking for is just plain regular C or C++.

For example write your program normally, but constrain yourself not to use any dynamic memory allocation (no new, delete, malloc, or free, or any of their friends, and make sure your libraries do the same), then you have that kind of system. You figure out in advance how much memory you need for everything you could do, and declare that memory statically (either function level static variables, or global variables). The compiler takes care of all the accounting the normal way, nothing special happens at the end of each scope, and no extra computation is necessary.

You can even configure your runtime environment to have a statically allocated stack space (this one isn't really under the compiler's control, more linker and operating system environment). Just figure out how deep your function call chain goes, and how much memory it uses (with a profiler or similar tool), an set it in your link options.

Without dynamic memory allocation (and thus no deallocation through either garbage collection or explicit management), you are limited to the memory you declared when you wrote the program. But that's ok, many programs don't need dynamic memory, and are already written that way. The real need for this shows up in embedded and real-time systems when you absolutely, positively need to know exactly how long an operation will take, how much memory (and other resources) it will use, and that the running time and the use of those resources can't ever change.

The great thing about C and C++ is that the language requires so little from the environment, and gives you the tools to do so much, that smart pointers or statically allocated memory, or even some special scheme that you dream up can be implemented. Requiring the use them, and the constraints you put on yourself just becomes a policy decision. You can enforce that policy with code auditing (use scripts to scan the source or object files and don't permit linking to the dynamic memory libraries)